# NSDateFormatter for Chinese date

Tags: objective-c, localization, nsdate, nsdateformatter, chinese-locale

I have watched Advanced topics ininternationalization in WWDC 2014 and they recommend like this. Also, we can use custom format for different language.So, I am doing like this.

```
if([[Helpers getLocale]isEqualToString:@"zh-Hans"] || [[Helpers getLocale]isEqualToString:@"zh-Hant"])
{
    formatDate.dateFormat = @"yyyy MMM d"; //TODO: how to set for Chinese? dd also not okay
}
else
{   //Default as English..en
    formatDate.dateFormat = @"d MMM yyyy";
}
```

However, for chinese language, I cannot set properly and I only get this. **2014 8月 22**. How can I set format for Chinese Date as shown in first picture? (with custom format)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is because I don't know Chinese language. We can use this format. **y年M月d日**

Answer (score 3):

You should use `dateFormatFromTemplate` method. This will take in your preferred date format and convert it to locale's format. This will introduce any additional special characters if it must and you do not have to worry about it.
As an example this is what I do to convert my preferred format of "dd MMM yyyy" to the equivalent format in Chinese languages.

```
// input format in this case is "dd MMM yyyy"
// when language is set to Chinese, I will change it accordingly like this. 

NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *language = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
    if ([language containsString:@"zh"])
    {
        format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:format options:0 locale:locale];
    }
// output format from this code for chinese languages is yyyy年M月dd日
```

You do not have to manually insert / remove special characters. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out `+dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:` -- it worked brilliantly. I had my format string set to @"MMM d (EEE)", and in Korean it's showing the month symbol correctly, but not the day symbol. Applying the method you mentioned fixed that!

Comment: Oh, this is cool. For Korean, that method literally inserts that day character into the format string: @"MMM d일 (EEE)" -- that's pretty awesome. And of course it does entirely different formatting for Spanish and inserts different characters for Japanese and Chinese. Very cool.

Comment: Got tripped up by this one too. Side note: I think this has been renamed to `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh_Hant_HK"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
//[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];//if you want show time, please enable this line

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString* str = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:date];
```